# Retrieving context menus from the form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the following code which is a private method inside the form and retrieve all context menus from the form. I feel, that it is not that concise as it should be. Would be grateful for any suggestions.

```
  private IEnumerable<ContextMenuStrip> GetContextMenus()
    {
        var type = this.GetType();
        var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var contextMenus = fields.Where(f => f.GetValue(this).GetType() == typeof(ContextMenuStrip));
        var menus = contextMenus.Select(f=> f.GetValue(this));
        return menus.Cast<ContextMenuStrip>();        
    }
```

Comment: Kettic DataGridView is able to [create custom data grid context menus](http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/gridview_context_menu_conditional.shtml) in C# to Data GirdView for Windows Forms applications

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine why do you do this via Reflection, I believe the same can be done by walking through `Controls` tree. Your method will not work if context menu has property `Generate member` set to `false` in designer.

```
var contextMenus = fields.Where(f => f.GetValue(this).GetType() == typeof(ContextMenuStrip));
var menus = contextMenus.Select(f=> f.GetValue(this));
return menus.Cast<ContextMenuStrip>();
```

Can be replaced with:

```
return fields.Select(f => f.GetValue(this)).OfType<ContextMenuStrip>();
```

Comment: Thank you.  Probably I should rewrite it using Controls collection.